# In spark scala how to minus 30 min from hours in strings like "2315" in variable to get back hours in string as "2245" in variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one requirement where hours are taken in variable in string as "2315" and I have to minus 30 mins from it and get output again back in variable in string as "2245".How to achieve this.Please help.
             e.g. var a = "2315"
                  var b = a - 30mins = "2245"

Answer (score 1):

var's are not recomended in scala. Use val instead.

In accordance with your question. you can do :

```
val a = "2315"
val b = (a.toLong - 30).toString
```

Use some library instead if you've to deal with time, like: jodatime or scalatime

Comment: Hi geek94,I too did the same but how to achieve using  jodatime or scalatime please elaborate with example,your current  example gives output as 2285 and I need 2245.